# C#: write in a file at url with c#

Tags: c#, file, file-io

I am using the code below to write some text into a file that is then uploaded to a url.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://domain/filename");
HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream file=Response.GetResponseStream();
StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(file);
wr.WriteLine("salam");
```

but it have an unhandled exception in line

```
 StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(file);
```

can anybody help me?

Comment: So close, you need to write to `request.GetRequestStream()` for an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc(v=vs.110).aspx#code-snippet-2

Comment: Do you want to upload or download?

Comment: Whats the exception?

Comment: Obviously you can't write to a read-only stream. So explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @PatrickHofman text file is ready in host and i wanna write in it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman file permision changed to 777,

Answer (score 0):

You can't write files over the HTTP protocol (unless you are using WebDAV, or similar technology). That's why what you are trying will always fail.

Maybe it's an idea to use FTP, using the [`FtpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) / [`FtpWebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebresponse(v=vs.110).aspx) classes.

Also see [MSDN: How to: Upload Files with FTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx).